# Building a web service for processing Json data with python

Tags: python, json, https, server, get

I am only told to create a pythonic web service. At the end of the day, I need to offer a **HTTPS endpoint** which will receive(from a post request), and be able to process/send back json objects from/to another web service.

To be able to receive post requests from other services, what kind of information do I need?

I have seen [some examples](https://howtodoinjava.com/python/python-httplib2-tutorial-http-getpost-examples/) using `httplib2` such as sending HTTP get and post requests when given a website like `www.something.com`. But in my case, since I do not know the IP address/URL of the data source, should I create a listener waiting for the incoming data? How to achieve this?

I am really new with building python web server and the requirement I am given is really vague. Thank you in advance for helping me break down this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Flask framework](http://flask.pocoo.org/), it can do everything you want and then some. I can especially recommend the [Quickstart: A Minimal Application](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) and the [JSON Support](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#module-flask.json) pages.

Enabling the build in debugger will help you a great deal as well.

All services is listening for incoming connections, so you are right about that :-)

Good luck!